# A way to hand off FTP connections from a daemon to a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ftp, daemon

I am going to make either a C or a Ruby daemon which will create FTP connections, keep the connections alive (ie. pool connections), and act as a proxy to FTP sites for my Rails app. This will allow my Rails app to communicate with FTP sites across AJAX calls and not have to reconnect to FTP sites with each AJAX call.

I'd like the daemon to pool connections, but, I'd like to not have to use it as a proxy because that's extra functionality and thus extra time.

**My question:** If I open an FTP connection in my daemon process, is there a way to simply hand off connections from the daemon to my Rails app?

So rather than do this in my Rails app

```
connection = Net::FTP.new('my.site.com')
connection.login
connection.get(remote_file_path, local_file_path)
```

I'd like to do something like this

```
daemon_reference = ???
connection = daemon.getConnection(some_key)
connection.get(remote_file_path, local_file_path)
```

Comment: Pass the fd through unix domain socket to pass the fd. But I have to check how to pass that fd to Net:FTP

Comment: What is the fd? Can you pass a resource (eg. FTP connection, database connection, file handle) via a local UNIX socket?

Answer (score 2):

Generally you cannot hand off connections from one process to another with one exception: When forking, the child process will inherit all connections from the parent. A normal fork operation leaves the child with the same set of file descriptors as the parent, and any open sockets are included in this set. This is a one-time operation, though, as new file descriptors will be created within the context of one process only.

You will probably have to proxy in order for this to work, but that won't be crazy hard. You'll just need a way for your external process to request a connection, make use of the connection, and then release the connection into the pool. This could be done FTP style where you communicate on one socket, and a second acts as a data channel.

This isn't as tricky as it sounds. You could create a UNIX socket called "proxy.sock" and have clients connect to that. One command could request a connection to a particular FTP destination and it would get a path back like "ftp.example.com.sock" which it can use to connect to that location. Bridging one stream socket to another isn't very tricky at that point and detecting when the socket is closed on the local end is routine.

UNIX sockets can be more convenient than TCP sockets since you won't have to worry about allocating, or running out of port numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response. What do you mean by "Bridging one stream socket to another?"

Comment: Basically connecting two sockets together. When there is data ready to read on one, write it to the other, and vice-versa. This is a standard feed-through proxy operation and EventMachine even has a special mode specifically to support it.